Numbers with this property show up frequently
I am looking for how many consecutive numbers $n = \prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{a_i}$ can have the property that $n$ does not share any divisors with
$$
\sigma(n) = \prod_{i=1}^r\left(1 + p_i + \cdots + p_i^{a_i}\right).
$$
Here, $n = \prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{a_i}$ is the prime decomposition of $n$.
From the formula for $\sigma(n)$, it is clear that a lot of numbers $n$ must share a divisor with $\sigma(n)$. For instance, any number $n$ of the form

$2\times 3\times (2k+1)$
$2\times 3 \times (3k+1)$ or $2\times 3 \times (3k+2)$
$2^2\times 7\times (2k+1)$
$2p$ where $p\ne 2$ is prime
$p^k$ where $p$ is prime
...

I think that numbers of this form cannot leave gaps of more than $5$ numbers.

If this is correct, how could I go about showing that numbers $n$ that share a divisor with $\sigma(n)$ show up frequently enough that, in any $6$ consecutive numbers, we must find at least one?


See A069059

Indeed, it seems that the longest consecutive sequence of numbers $n$ with $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))=1$ is given by $n=1,2,3,4,5$.

Note that also $\gcd(p^e,\sigma(p^e))=1$, since $\gcd(p,\frac{p^k-1}{p-1})=1$. So the sequence contains all prime powers.

From the given formula for $\sigma(n)$, it's easy to check that $\sigma(n)$ is odd precisely when $n$ is either a perfect square or twice a perfect square. In particular, when $n$ is even, we always have $\gcd(n,\sigma(n))\ge2$ unless $n$ is a perfect square or twice a perfect square. Any set of six consecutive positive integers contains three even numbers, and (since squares can't be that close to each other) at most one of those even numbers is a perfect square and at most one of them is twice a perfect square; so there can never be six consecutive numbers $n$ all of which are coprime with $\sigma(n)$.
From an analytic number theory perspective, one can show that for most numbers $n$, being coprime to $\sigma(n)$ is equivalent to not having any prime factors less than about $\log\log n$. (One shows that most values of $\sigma(n)$ are divisible by all primes less than $\log\log n$.) So the number of integers $n\le x$ that are coprime to $\sigma(n)$ is asymptotic to $e^{-\gamma} x/\log\log\log x$ (so density $0$, but still quite a lot of them). I know this has been explicitly done for the related problem of $n$ being coprime with $\phi(n)$, and I suspect this $\sigma$ version is also in the literature somewhere.
